# Cross product of a set is compact implies constituent set is compact

Tags: general-topology

> Question:
>
> Let X and Y be topological spaces.
> Prove that if $X \times Y$ is compact with respect to the product topology then X and Y are compact.

I've been stuck on this for a hour or so and I think what I'm missing is a subtle connection.

Attempt:

Suppose that $X \times Y$ is a compact product space.
This implies that there is a collection $C_{X \times Y}=\left \{ U_{\alpha}:\alpha \in J \right \}$ of open subsets $U_{\alpha}$ that is an open cover of $X \times Y$.

In fact, every open cover of $X \times Y$ contains a finite subcollection that covers $X \times Y$.

> Recall:
>
> The product topology on the product space $X \times Y$ is generated by the basis $\bar{B}=\left \{ T \times U:T \in \tau, U \in \nu  \right \}=\tau \times \nu$

This implies that any element $\left ( x,y \right )$ in the basis element B of $\bar{B} \subseteq U_{\alpha}$ for any open set $U_{\alpha}$.

To show that X is compact, we need to show that there is an open cover of X that contains X and that every open cover of X contains a finite subcollection that covers X. The same applies to Y.

Any useful help to take me further is much appreciated.

Comment: Aren't the projections $\pi_b : \prod_{a\in A}X_a \to X_b$ continuous surjections?

Comment: You will need to assume $X,Y$ are nonempty.  The projection $\varnothing \times [0,1] \to [0,1]$ may not be surjective...

Comment: @GEdgar: But in that case, the assertion is false. $\varnothing \times X$ is compact (since it s empty) for any $X$, whether $X$ is compact or not. So that would have to be implicit in OP's assertion if it is to be true.

Comment: Thus, my comment is to the OP, not MPW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To proceed using open covers: Let $\{U_{\alpha} : \alpha \in J\}$ be an open cover of $X$ (say). The family $\{U_{\alpha} \times Y : \alpha \in J\}$ is an open cover of $X \times Y$. Since $X \times Y$ is compact, there exists a finite subcover, say $\{U_{i} \times Y : i = 1, \dots, n\}$. The collection $\{U_{i} : i = 1, \dots, n\}$ is a cover of $X$. Since $\{U_{\alpha} : \alpha \in J\}$ was an arbitrary cover, $X$ is compact. Then argue similarly for $Y$.

Comment: Promising and I'm leaning towards your contribution. 
Is it valid to assume the statement to be true for what we want to proof?
I've always understand that to show that a space X is compact, we have to show first(conventionally) that the space X has an open cover. But it seems that we could actually validly assume space X has an open cover, then, via a finite subcollection of the open cover determine if space X is compact.

Comment: Every topological space $X$ admits an open cover: Take $X$ itself (a cover containing one set), or use the axioms of a topology to pick, for each $x$ in $X$, an open set $U_{x}$ containing $x$, and consider the resulting family $\{U_{x} : x \in X\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The projection map $\pi_X\colon X\times Y\to X$ is continuous and surjective; the image of a compact space under a continuous map is…

Comment: Doesn't the projection map maps a set X to a set of equivalence class X*?

Comment: Different use of the word "projection".

Comment: Which one is it then?

Comment: Well, the image of a compact space under a continuous map is compact.
is this just any arbitrary 'projection' map?

Comment: @Mathematicing $\pi_X(x,y)=x$